# initial ng-model values not setting select correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Given the following angular component, [with a working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/phP5rFBQi1Bn6Rf5N6lZ?p=preview).

```
export const AppComponent = {
  template: 'see below'
  controller: class AppComponent {
    static $inject = ["$http"];
    constructor(public $http) {
    }
    $onInit() {
      this.$http.get("types.json").then(_ => this.types = _.data);
      this.$http.get("docs.json").then(_ => this.documents = _.data);
    }
  }
};
```

With template

```
<div>
    <h3>Types</h3>
    <div ng-repeat='document in $ctrl.types'>{{document.name}}</div>

    <h3>Docs</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="status in $ctrl.documents">
        <span ng-bind="status.documentType.name"></span>
        <ul ng-repeat="document in status.correspondence">
            <li>{{document.name}}</li>
            <li>
                {{document.documentTypeId}}
                <!-- ng options: can't seem to get correct mapping for just the `ID`,  
                     it always binds the while type object.
                     ng-options="type.name for type in $ctrl.types track by type.id"
                -->
                <select
                    ng-model="document.documentTypeId">
                    <option ng-repeat="type in $ctrl.types" value="{{type.id}}">{{type.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The inital values for the `select` are not set, **but** when the values are **changed** by clicking a particular type, **the model is updated** correctly.

> why are the select values not being set correctly from the model when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngOptions` supports custom child property to become `ngModel` for the dropdown. Like this,

```
ng-options="type.id as type.name for type in $ctrl.types"
            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

which can be read as `value as label for collection`. But, this can't be used along with `track by`. You have to pick [one or other.](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564#issuecomment-51615589)

And, in this case, we could get rid of `track by` since we don't have too complex objects to iterate over.

[**working example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0wrQpXjJUfLamC2emKlt?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use This Code:

```
<select 
                ng-options="type.id as (type.name) for type in $ctrl.types"
                ng-model="document.documentTypeId">
            </select>
```

This Code Will be Solve problem.